# different results when calculating 1st moment using numpy vs scipy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

Why am I getting 2 different answers when calculating the mean (1st moment) using NumPy vs SciPy?

```
import numpy as np
import scipy
from scipy.stats import moment

arr = np.array([1, 2, 3])
print(np.mean(arr))
print(scipy.stats.moment(arr, moment=1))
```

The output:

```
2.0
0.0
```

Comment: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.9.1/scipy/stats/_stats_py.py#L1194

Comment: `stats.moment` returns the *central* moment.